# android How to add header for the sub webview

Tags: android, webview, header

I use

```
WebView.loadUrl (String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)
```

to add header when loadurl ,but when click link ,go to new page,the header is missed,how can I add it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use webViewClient

There are many example use your header and webview in your layout

Comment: I find shouldInterceptRequest  this method  but api level is 11,Any other method?